# SSH error 10054, Flow Socket Error Receiving Bytes

Tags: sockets, ssh, digital-ocean

While connecting to server over SSH .. The connection got established but, after 1-2 seconds it got disconnected giving error message.

Tried Bitvise SSH Client, WinSCP. Same issue.

Error `"Flow Socket Error receiving Bytes. Windows error 10054, An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host."`

Not able to do anything. Tried almost everything I found.

Ubuntu Server, Digital Ocean

Comment: I don't know your environment but there might be some deep inspection firewall or Intrusion Detection System in the path which does not like the SSH connections and thus injects a RST packet to close it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich using windows 8. Till yesterday it was working fine. Even I didn't installed anything new in between. Tried a few firewall stuff found online .. but no luck. I even think its some firewall issue.. Not able to identify though..

Answer (score 6):

On Bitvise SSH Client main window, Login Tab, unchecking "Enable Obfuscation" did the trick for me.

Comment: This fixed it in my case.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me too and saved my day.

Comment: Unfortunately, this trick did not work for me.

Comment: did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you can get this error if Bitvise server has blocked the IP you are trying to connect from.
Solution: open Bitvise server > Sessions Tab > Manage Blocked IP's and unblock the offending IP

I've had this with a user today. It turned out the user was connecting using the Bitvise client but was also trying to connect with the same account through an orchistration in Cast Iron. The Orchistration was set up to login with a password and Bitvise Server had blocked the IP address she was connecting from.

Comment: .. Where or how would I open Bitvise Server you talk about?